# 55 minutes to publish a simple project to google app engine from the command line

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've tried with the sdk 1.6.0, and with 1.6.1 (just out) with the same results. I would like to ask if it's normal to have a 55 minutes wait time before the upload script asks me for email and password and starts the actual upload, which took 3-4 additional minutes (the first time and few seconds the second time with 1.6.1).

Here is my command line, I'm using Linux Ubuntu and Java 1.6.0_23 OpenJDK

```
~/bin/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.1/bin/appcfg.sh update Task-0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/
```

**UPDATE**: As for the comments, it seems is not a common problem, so I'm investigating with different tests, and will share the results in a few days.

**UPDATE 2**: A hand assembled project (JARs manually put in WEB-INF/lib) was uploaded in matter of seconds. However, the following Spring Roo project caused the problem (repeatable for me). My setup: Linux Ubuntu 11.10, OpenJDK 1.6.0_23, Google App Engine SDK 1.6.1, Maven 3.0.3, Spring Roo 1.1.5 - Here is how I create and upload the project.

```
$ mkdir task
$ cd task
$ roo
roo> project --topLevelPackage task --java 6
roo> persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE \
    --applicationId <yourAppId>
roo> entity --class task.Task
roo> field string --fieldName description --notNull --sizeMin 3 --sizeMax 512
roo> field boolean --fieldName completed --notNull 
roo> controller all --package task.controller
roo> exit
$ mvn package
$ cd target
$ ~/bin/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.1/bin/appcfg.sh update task-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
```

If anybody tries it, please confirm if you've the same problem (or not!).

Comment: Have you tried again? Still 55 minutes?

Comment: @systempuntoout weird eh? I am now trying with 1.6.1, I've just downloaded it..

Comment: Maybe you've encountered some dns problem to resolve `appengine.google.com`, I'm using 1.6.0 without any problem.

Comment: @systempuntoout could be, but unlikely because I'm using google public DNS (`8.8.8.8` `8.8.4.4`). It seems to get stuck on `8% Compiling jsp file`, could it be because I've .jspx and no .jsp?

Comment: Definitely not normal - even so for a simple project. Once, I had this  problem when it did take a while (15 mins or so) to ask for the password. Then it again took a while to reach the 99% stage & then, kept trying over & over again & finally failed after another 15-20 mins or so. I tried an  hour later & it went back to normal. Let us know how it goes with 1.6.1

Comment: with 1.6.1, 55 minutes to go to the upload phase, but then it took only a few seconds for the upload :-)

Comment: Voting to close because the question is too localized - "This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet." Obviously not everyone experiences this, and you haven't provided us any details which would allow us to distinguish your situation from everyone else's, for whom it works fine.

Comment: @NickJohnson to me it happens *every* time, possible that there is no way to debug the situation and your response is to ignore the problem?

Comment: @stivlo Then provide us with details of what you've tried. Does it still happen on a different machine? What about with a different app, or a different app ID? What about with a different user account? For how long has this been an issue?

Comment: @NickJohnson thank you, I will experiment and come back with details and results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replayed the same example with Spring Roo 1.2.0. The only difference is that the `entity` command is now renamed `entity jpa`, to differentiate with MongoDB entities.

```
entity --class task.Task
```

becomes

```
entity jpa --class task.Task
```

Uploading to Google App Engine now takes approximately 1 minute and a half. While it's not blazingly fast, is now an acceptable wait.

So the solution to my problem, is to upgrade to Spring Roo 1.2.0, which BTW, was released a few days after this question was posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's perfectly normal - remember that GAE is based on existing load, and there is a geometric wait time for pollin the server when deploying.

If wait times are exorbitant .... Then you can just wait several hours --- in my experience, waiting overnight is generally a good policy.

http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleAppEngine/2011-08/msg01027.html

Comment: I'll try to make it clearer: an app created with roo and maven-gae-plugin takes 55 minutes to go online, after that I publish another simple hand assembled app in seconds, then I try again with the first app and still 55 minutes, then I try again with the hand assembled and still only a few seconds. Also I've mentioned that it hangs on JSP compilation **before** even connecting to GAE for the upload. Thank you for the answer, but I don't think I'm in the case you're mentioning.

Comment: Yes ---- looks like your issue is related to the specifics of your source code.